# Change "salt length" parameter in PSS parameters for Bouncycastle

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, digital-signature, bouncycastle

I want to sign a message.

I am using Bouncycastle (more accurately, the Android version, SpongyCastle).

My code is the following :

```
Signature instance = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA/PSS", "BC");
MGF1ParameterSpec mgf1ParameterSpec = new MGF1ParameterSpec("SHA-256");
PSSParameterSpec pssParameterSpec = new PSSParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1",mgf1ParameterSpec , 512, 1);
instance.setParameter(pssParameterSpec);
instance.initSign(privateKey);
instance.update(msg.getBytes());
byte[] signature = instance.sign();
```

When trying to check the signature with another device (and another technology), I noticed that the "salt_length" was not '512' but '32'.
And more than that, if I modify the `PSSParameterSpec` constructor, it doesn't matter, the "salt_length" will always be '32', even if I don't use the `instance.setParameter(pssParameterSpec)`.

It looks like `instance.setParameter(pssParameterSpec)` does nothing.
Is it normal ?

Any idea how to change the value of "salt_length" ?

Comment: I don't have Android, but in BC 1.52 saltlen is **in octets** (consistent with PKCS#1v2.1 = rfc3447) not bits -- and 512 octets is too big. If I do 512/8, or other octet counts, it definitely comes in the encoded parameters and looking at the source it should be used, though I can't debug effectively because my Eclipse dislikes the bcprov-debug jar. I do wonder why you want salt larger than the **default which is the hash-output size** and indeed is used if I don't `.setParameter(p)`; I haven't gone through the actual proofs but AIUI there is no benefit in more.

Comment: In fact, I tried with vlaues `0`, `1`, `8`, `32` ... it's always the same, on the verifying side, I need to set it to `32` :-/

Note: I don't necessarily need a `salt_length` to `512`, I just want to be able to set it myself so I can have the same value than on the verifying side.

Comment: Are you sure the verify side is telling you correctly? I looked at the external (ASN.1) data -- and selected saltlen is definitely there for BC 1.52 and also 1.46 and 1.54 (the oldest and newest I have). Assuming https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle is the correct source, browsing a few relevant classes I notice no differences from BC other than the (expected) rename, and it looks to me like the saltlen logic is present and should work, though I didn't spend the time to download and build and try it.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of head-scratching it appears the order of `initSign`/`initVerify` and `setParameter` does matter on Android.

Using the same algorithm (without BouncyCastle in my case) requires setting the parameters **after** initialization, otherwise the default values are used:

```
signature.initVerify(publicKey);
signature.setParameter(new PSSParameterSpec(...));
```

This of course raises more questions about portability. The only lead I managed to find is this [JDK bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8216039), although in my case the same provider is selected in both cases and still fails when setting the parameters before initialization.

Comment: thanks to your answer, i was able to fix my own signature verification issue when setting a custom salt length