# BouncyCastleProvider not picked for Signature object

Tags: java, android, cryptography, bouncycastle

I have an RSASSA-PSS/SHA256 signature to verify and I am using `BouncyCastleProvider` and Android system. Please have a look at the following snippet:

```
Security.removeProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
Security.insertProviderAt(BouncyCastleProviderSingleton.getInstance(), 1);

try {
      RSAPublicKey publicKey = rsaKey.toRSAPublicKey();

      String jcaAlg = "RSASSA-PSS";
      PSSParameterSpec pssSpec = new PSSParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, 32, 1);

      Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(jcaAlg, BouncyCastleProviderSingleton.getInstance());
      signature.setParameter(pssSpec);
      signature.initVerify(publicKey);
      signature.update(obj2.getSigningInput());
      boolean v = signature.verify(obj2.getSignature().decode());

      Signature signature2 = Signature.getInstance(jcaAlg);
      signature2.setParameter(pssSpec);
      signature2.initVerify(publicKey);
      signature2.update(obj2.getSigningInput());
      boolean v2 = signature2.verify(obj2.getSignature().decode());
} catch (Exception ex) {
      throw new EncryptionException("Extracting public RSA key from certificate failed", ex);
}
```

Basically, I am trying to verify `obj2` signature twice. One time, I supply `BouncyCastleProvider` directly, passing it into `Signature.getInstance()` method. The other time I am skipping this argument and I trust `BouncyCastleProvider` will be picked anyway, because I inserted it at the most-prioritized place in `Provider` list. This probably works as expected, as both `signature.getProvider()` and `signature2.getProvider()` return the same instance of `BouncyCastleProvider`. However, values of `v` and `v2` are different. First verification succeeds (this is the correct behavior, `v` equals `true`), and second fails (`v` equals `false`). Why would that happen if in the end both `Signature`s should be using the same provider?

I am using an emulator running API 28.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: If obj2.getSigningInput() is returning a ByteBuffer, you would have to rewind() it between the two verifications.

Comment: I have run this on the Android emulator (API 28) and confirmed this problem. I've run it on a JVM (Java 11) and it works normally, i.e. both verifications return true. I modified it a little to use fixed byte arrays, so the ByteBuffer or whatever objects OP is using are not an issue @PeterDettman. I'm still looking at the code to see if there is something obvious I'm missing.

Comment: What I noticed is that the call `signature2.initVerify(publicKey);` on Android causes the `signature2.sigSpi` to be replaced with one based on SHA1 hash functions rather the passed-in PSSParameterSpec. I have no idea why that would happen.

Comment: As President James K. Polk has already figured out: In contrast to Java, `PSSParameterSpec` is ignored under Android without specification of the BC provider and the default values (SHA-1 for both digests, salt length 20) are used (at least for API 28). Presumably this is a bug. A workaround for this specific case is to call `setParameter` _after_ `initSign`/`initVerify`, see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56064919). There may be a relation to [JDK-8216040](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8216040) and [JDK-8216039](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8216039).

Comment: Thanks guys. We're (BC) familiar with this issue on the JVM of course, but hadn't so far seen it reported for Android. Is anyone able to quickly confirm this on the latest Android API?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I can confirm this also fails on API 30 and 31. And that a trick with calling ``setParameter`` after ```init[...]``` solves the problem.